# Selenium WebDriver cannot find element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the sample webpage code

```
<div class="size1of2 fllt">
    <div id="iad-service" class="tmargin2 rite fllt service-check"></div>
    <div class="fk-font-13 fk-font-regular">hi</div>
</div>
```

I want to find the "class" element using Selenium WebDriver.

Here is the code I tried.

```
String abc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'iad-service')]/@class")).getText();
System.out.println(abc);
```

When I tried this code(//div[contains(@id,'iad-service')]/@class) in the XPath Checker Addon, I am getting this output.

```
tmargin2 rite fllt service-check
```

But using WebDriver, I am getting an error. I want the output to be the content of the class which is.

```
tmargin2 rite fllt service-check
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: what error log do you get from the execution?

Comment: has the html any `frames`?

Comment: @SatelliteSD NO frames..

Comment: @guido Unable to find element

//div[contains(@id,'iad-service')]/@class

Comment: do you wait until your element is present or are you trying to find it immediatly, taking the risk of that is isn't already loaded?

Comment: @SatelliteSD I waited till it ends. Actually I had to use getAttribute instead of getvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the div element, then retrive the class attribute value:

```
String abc = driver.findElement
               (By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'iad-service')]")).getAttribute("class");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
WebElement id=wd.findElement(By.id("iad-service"));
    String className=id.getAttribute("class");
```